# How to write all the sentences with the word "apple" from a txt file

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have tried this using regex, loops and simple functions as well but cannot figure out anything. here are the few codes I have tried.

```
import re
fp = open("apple.txt")
re.findall(r"([^.]*?apple[^.]*\.)",fp)
```

Comment: `filter(lambda x : "police" in x, open('file.txt').read().splitlines())` may be this works for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("./WABA-crash.txt", "r") as input:
    content = input.read().replace('\n', '')
sentences = list(map(str.strip, content.split(".")))
with open("./resultFile.txt", "w") as output:
    for result in sentences:
        if ('police' in result or 'Police' in result):
            output.write(f'{result}. \n')
```

There is no need for regex. It might not be the cleanest answer but it works. This is the beauty of Python. When working with files I recommend you to use with open instead of open(). Since this will automatically close the for you. Otherwise you'd need to use the close() method at the end of your file.

Hope this helps you! Enjoy

Comment: you did it right but I need the output to be in a new text file that is the problem. I have tried like this but it is only writing one line and getting terminated.                            with open("./WABA-crash.txt", "r") as fic:
    content = fic.read().replace('\n', '')
sentences = list(map(str.strip, content.split(".")))
for result in sentences:
    if 'police' in result:
        with open('readme.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(f'{result}.')

Comment: One second I will edit it

Comment: @chaitanyachitturi You are welcome. I changed a little thing. instead of "a" for append it is now write "w" so you don't have to clear the file all the time

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex that can be quite complicated in order to be solid (you need to account many different type of potential sentence form) a good solution may be using a NLP library like NLTK or Spacy.

Here is how to tokenize with nltk:

```
from nltk import tokenize

with open("WABA-crash.txt") as file:
    content=file.read()
    sentences=tokenize.sent_tokenize(content)

    police_sentences=[x for x in sentences if "police" in x]

print(police_sentences)
```

Comment: what you did was right for extracting the sentences with police word but I want all those sentences to be written to a new .txt file

Comment: Well, you can do that yourself. Just open a new file, loop trough the sentences list and write it on the file.